# Buying bitcoin is easy, but how do you get it back?

Tags: sell-bitcoins, canada

I just signed up on coinbase to see how it works. I bought 2$ (CAD) worth of bitcoin. I even managed to change it back into Canadian $. But I don't see any option to withdraw the money. Without the option to withdraw the money at any time, it's really hard to rationalize buying bitcoin. The thing is, I really want to. Badly. What can I do?

After searching for a pretty long time, I found this post confirming my fears. 
[image]

> Our banking partner in Canada shutdown last year. With them shutting down, we no longer have access to deposit funds to Canadian Bank accounts. Fortunately, we were able to provide credit card/debit card access to our Canadian customers so they can continue buying digital currency. We hope to restore bank account access to provide Sells again, but we don't have a timeframe for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sell bitcoins in an third party exchange. (First you need to send the bitcoins to address specified in exchange)
For example checkout a trade ad on localbitcoins.com

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I was already aware of localbitcoins but as you can see, the prices are a ripoff. First, you lose a % of your money when you buy bitcoins, then you lose an even greater % when you sell them at that site. It makes buying bitcoin very risky and not worth it. Is there no way to buy and sell at market value (or close)? That is really my question.